# Rotating an axis system in 3D

Tags: vectors, 3d, rotations

I'm trying to get my head around a 3D rotation problem which I have simply not been able to solve for days.

Suppose I have a 3D space (`x`, `y` and `z` axes). I construct three vectors (x, y, z) which are simply unit vectors in each of the axis directions.

Suppose we now begin to rotate the 3 vectors taken other vectors in the system to be the axes of rotation. The first rotation is about the `y` axis by `a` degrees. This would give two new vectors `(x', y, z')`.

Now we take this new group of three unit vectors and rotate them about the `x'` axis by `b` degrees, giving `(x', y', z'')`.

Then my question is, what will be the new orientation of the z-axis? (ie. what would be the value of the unit vector `z''`)?

I'd appreciate a step-by-step explanation as I don't have an extensive level of mathematics experience and want to understand how this works.

**Edit:**

Thanks to Matti P.'s comment I have looked through the page on Euler angles and Tait-Bryan angles and can see that this is where the solution lies, however, there are still some parts of the solution which I don't understand:

1) In my question, I am interested in performing two rotations (one about the `x` and the second about the `y` axis), not three as is shown in what I have read about Tait-Bryan angles. I am interested in getting the unit vector of the new `z''` axis after the transformations.

2) I am still confused as to the formulas given in the article particularly with regards to the vectors. After each transformation, how can I get the unit vectors of the new intrinsic axes with reference to the original "environmental" axes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately the wikipedia page is very extensive in mathematical explanation and I find it a bit difficult to follow. Can you show me step-by-step how to get from the values of a and b which I defined in the question to the unit vector of z''?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what I am describing is an intrinsic Tait-Bryan rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way of calculating rotations in 3D is by using Euler angles and matrix multiplication. I hope you are familiar with matrix multiplication.

Let's start by taking a vector $\vec{v}$ in 3 dimensions. This can be any vector of your choise. In the end, we will take $\vec{v} = z$-axis. Now, if we take any matrix $R$ whose determinant is $\det{R}=1$ and calculate
$$
R\vec{v}
$$
it turns out that this is some rotation of the original vector. It points to a new direction, and the length does not change.

The simplest rotation is a rotation about the $x$-axis, with an angle $\alpha$. Omitting the proof, it can be shown that the matrix
$$
R_x(\alpha) = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos{\alpha} & -\sin{\alpha} \\
0 & \sin{\alpha} & \cos{\alpha} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
can be used for this. Maybe you have seen something like this before? I suggest that you carry out some example calculations with some vectors of your choise. Do you see how the $x$-coordinate of the rotated vector doesn't change when you multiply them? Okay, good.

The other elementary rotation matrices are of course around the $y$ and $z$-axes. As a summary, all of the three elementary matrices are
\begin{equation}
R_X(x) = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos{x} & -\sin{x} \\
0 & \sin{x} &  \cos{x} \\
\end{array} \right]
\qquad
R_Y(x) = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{x}  &  0 & \sin{x}  \\
0  & 1 & 0  \\
-\sin{x} & 0 & \cos{x}  \\
\end{array} \right]
\qquad
R_Z(x) = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{x}  & -\sin{x} & 0 \\
\sin{x}  & \cos{x}  & 0 \\
0  & 0  & 1 \\
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

These rotation matrices can then be combined. The most common Euler angle rotation order is the extrinsic $xyz$-order, which produces the (a bit complex-looking)
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
R &= R_Z(\psi) R_Y(\theta)  R_X(\phi) \\
 &= 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\psi}  & -\sin{\psi} & 0 \\
\sin{\psi}  & \cos{\psi}  & 0 \\
0  & 0  & 1 \\
\end{array} \right]
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\theta}  &  0 & \sin{\theta}  \\
0  & 1 & 0  \\
-\sin{\theta} & 0 & \cos{\theta}  \\
\end{array} \right]
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos{\phi} & -\sin{\phi} \\
0 & \sin{\phi} &  \cos{\phi} \\
\end{array} \right] 
\\
&= 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\theta}\cos{\psi} & \cos{\psi} \sin{\theta} \sin{\phi} - \cos{\phi} \sin{\psi} & \cos{\phi} \cos{\psi} \sin{\theta} + \sin{\phi} \sin{\psi} \\
%
\cos{\theta}\sin{\psi} & \cos{\phi} \cos{\psi} + \sin{\theta} \sin{\phi} \sin{\psi} & \cos{\phi}\sin{\theta} \sin{\psi} - \cos{\psi} \sin{\phi} \\
%
-\sin{\theta}   & \cos{\theta}\sin{\phi} & \cos{\theta}\cos{\phi}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

This just means that the first rotation is carried out about the original $x$ axis (rotation by angle $\phi$), the second rotation is carried out about the original $y$-axis (angle $\theta$) and the last rotation is carried out about the original $z$-axis (angle $\psi$). The word "extrinsic" means that the axes by which the second and third rotation are carried out, do not change as a function of the previous rotations. So they are the "original" axes that remain fixed during the whole process.

---

The rotation order that you are requesting is an intrinsic $yxz$-rotation. Note that the previous calculations were only applied to the extrinsic rotation orders, which is the opposite of intrinsic. However, **it can be shown that in order to calculate the intrinsic rotation, you only need to reverse the rotation order and then calculate the equivalent extrensic rotation**. Proof for this is again omitted. So now we want to have the extrinsic $zxy$ rotation. This is merely a reordering of the previous example, resulting in 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
R &=  R_Y(\theta)  R_X(\phi) R_Z(\psi) \\
 &= 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\theta}  &  0 & \sin{\theta}  \\
0  & 1 & 0  \\
-\sin{\theta} & 0 & \cos{\theta}  \\
\end{array} \right]
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos{\phi} & -\sin{\phi} \\
0 & \sin{\phi} &  \cos{\phi} \\
\end{array} \right] 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\psi}  & -\sin{\psi} & 0 \\
\sin{\psi}  & \cos{\psi}  & 0 \\
0  & 0  & 1 \\
\end{array} \right]
\\
&= 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\theta}\cos{\psi} + \sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}\sin{\psi} & - \cos{\theta}\sin{\psi}+\cos{\psi}\sin{\theta}\sin{\psi} & \cos{\phi}\sin{\theta} \\
\cos{\phi}\sin{\psi} & \cos{\phi}\cos{\psi} & - \sin{\phi}\\
-\cos{\psi}\sin{\theta} + \cos{\theta}\sin{\phi}\sin{\psi} & \sin{\theta}\sin{\psi} + \cos{\theta}\cos{\psi}\sin{\phi} & \cos{\theta}\cos{\phi}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
(I recommend you double-check this calculation, because it's very easy to make a mistake in the multiplication). In your case, $\psi=0$, simplifying the result a bit:
$$
R = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta}\sin{\phi} & \cos{\phi}\sin{\theta} \\
0 & \cos{\phi} & - \sin{\phi} \\
-\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}\sin{\phi} & \cos{\theta}\cos{\phi}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
You were asking about the new components of the $z$-axis, in particular, so we must multiply this with the corresponding vector:
$$
R \vec{z} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta}\sin{\phi} & \cos{\phi}\sin{\theta} \\
0 & \cos{\phi} & - \sin{\phi} \\
-\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}\sin{\phi} & \cos{\theta}\cos{\phi}
\end{array}
\right]
\left( 
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{array}
\right)
= \left( 
\begin{array}{c}
-\sin{\theta} \\ \cos{\theta}\sin{\phi} \\ \cos{\theta}\cos{\phi}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Huh, quite a calculation! So just plug in $\theta=a$ and $\phi=b$ to get the result.